# Bijection maps from $(0,1)$ to the real numbers

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm wondering why $ f(x) = e^{2\pi i x + \pi/2}$ is a bijection from $(0,1)$ to the real numbers when the domain is $(0,1)$. Is $ f(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$ also a bijection? Detailed explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Wait!!! $f(x) = e^{2\pi i x + \pi/2} \in \mathbb{C} \neq \mathbb{R}$... To have a bijection, I think you should define a function $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, but in this case you defined $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This is not a bijection from $(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ as user @the_candyman points out, your function is from $(0,1)\to \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
f(x)
 = e^{\pi/2} \left[ e^{2\pi i x} \right]
 = e^{\pi/2} \left[ \cos(2\pi x) + i\sin(2\pi x) \right]
$$
which is mapping $(0,1)$ to a circle in the complex plane with radius $e^{\pi/2}$. Take note that since neither $0$ nor $1$ are in the domain, the point $1+0i$ will not be included in the image.

This is indeed a bijection between the real interval and the indicated part of the complex circle, but not sure this is what you expect.

Your suggested curve is a similar circle with unit radius...

Comment: Yes. That's what my question is supposed to ask.

Comment: But is $ f(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$  also a bijection?

Comment: @bt203 I am not doing your work for you. There is enough information in this answer to figure it our yourself. If there is a particular part of this problem you do not understand, please ask again about which part.

Comment: I think it is. My reasoning is that $ f(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$ is a bijection from $(0,1)$ to the unit circle. Then I can define a second bijection from the points on the unit circle except $1+0i$ to the real numbers. Is that correct?

Comment: @bt203 correct indeed

Answer (score 0):

If you apply [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) you get 
$$e^{2\pi i x}=\cos {2 \pi x}+i\sin{2 \pi x}$$
so the result is not real unless $x$ is an integer or half integer.  It cannot be a bijection.  Adding $\frac \pi 2$ to the exponent multiplies the right side by $e^{\pi/2}$ but that does not change the argument.

Answer (score 0):

A second step is needed to establish bijection. Hint: think about how you can establish a bijection geometrically between the unit circle(minus one point) and the real numbers